# Word Interop (COM) Proofing Options

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, styles, interop, proof

I have documents that do not retain their proofing options.
I have some code that now ensures all styles are set to the correct language and has proofing turned on:

```
For Each s As Style In oDocument.Styles
  Select Case s.Type
    Case WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeCharacter, WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph, WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeTable
      s.NoProofing = False
      s.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK
  End Select
Next
```

If I check the proofing options in the document without selecting any text, the following is displayed:
Proofing Options, No Text Selected

[image]

If I check the proofing options in the document with all text selected, the following is displayed: Proofing Options, All Text Selected

[image]

I have tried the following code snippet, but it did not work:

```
For Each range As Range In oDocument.Words
  range.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK
  range.NoProofing = False
  range.LanguageDetected = False
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior described in the question indicates mixed language formatting is present in the document.

Firstly, language formatting can be applied directly (similar to font formatting) rather than being controlled solely by styles. The language defined in a style will *not* override direct language formatting.

Additionally, "odd" behavior with language formatting often occurs when a document was created on a machine where the OS default language is different from Word's default language. The problem began with Office 97, where Microsoft changed Word's default behavior and has it check the Windows language and apply it to a new document if Word's default language is not identical. The information is written deeply into the document structure, where the Word UI is not able to change it. It can only be removed by editing the underlying Word Open XML.

Due to massive complaints by professionals who use Word, the behavior was somewhat alleviated in later versions to the point where selecting the entire body of the document (Ctrl+A) then applying the desired language directly could mostly prevent newly added text from being incorrectly formatted with the Windows language.

If manually selecting the entire document and applying the language directly does not change the behavior (object model equivalent `Document.Content.LanguageID =`), the only recourse would be to delve into the document's "zip package", inspect the XML to track down where the other language is stored, and remove it. This information can be used to create a solution with the Open XML SDK (or using standard Packaging and XML namespaces in the .NET Framework) so that it can be used on "any" document (YMMV)

Note: I have done this manually, but it was some time ago, so I don't remember exactly in which XML file in the zip package the Windows language is written.

Comment: I have extracted the document files, searched them for <w:noProof w:val="true"/> and <w:noProof w:val="1"/> and it does not find any occurences. From this i would assume that the 'Do not check spelling or grammar' would be off?

Comment: I ahve just checked against a 'field' in the footer, in particular teh DocumentName field, and this has 'Do not check spelling or grammar' checked. could this be the issue?

Comment: Do either of the above 2 comments provide any relevant information?

Comment: What's in the Footer is irrelevant as far as the code in the question goes: that deals only with the main body of the document. You may find these links to articles I wrote a *long* time ago informative http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/LangFmt.htm and perhaps especially http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/mergfaq.htm#SpellMrg if you really thnk the problem is with a field result.